# Density operator

Tags: quantum-cryptography, quantum-key-distribution

How I calculate density operator for pure quantum state for bb84 in 2D?

BB84 protocol, proposed in 1984 by Bennett and Brassard – that's where the name comes from. The idea is to encode every bit of the secret key into the polarization state of a single photon.

Comment: The [density operator of a pure quantum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Pure_and_mixed_states) $|\psi\rangle$ is simply its outer product $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. For each of the four BB84 states you should be able to write down the matrix representation of the corresponding operator in the standard computational basis.

Comment: @DanielShiu, many thanks for your answer my question.

Comment: @DanielShiu Do you mind converting your comment to an answer? It seems sufficient, even though it is rather - eh - succinct.

Answer (score 1):

The [density operator of a pure quantum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Pure_and_mixed_states/) $|\psi\rangle$ is simply its outer product with itself: $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. For each of the four BB84 states $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|+\rangle$, $|-\rangle$ you should be able to write down the matrix representation of the corresponding operator in the standard computational basis.